# How to use another laptop as extended monitor?

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors

Both laptops have Windows 7. I want to use Laptop B as extended monitor to Laptop A. At the same time, I should be able to use Laptop B as a standalone laptop.

Also, I do want to use this connection through USB or any wired means. But definitely not WiFi or any wireless connection.

How to do it? Any software? Which cord do I need?

Answer (score 0):

Any network connection can do the work. You can use remote desktop, vnc. But you can't use laptop as monitor only